# JavaScript enum Keyword

Tags: javascript

I am a C ++ programmer (not very good), and I know what enum is. When I was reading about lexical grammar ([Source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)), I saw a new keyword, enum. I tried it on NodeJS. And it works! (Well yes, but actually no ...).

```
enum someEnum {
    
}
```

And NodeJS throws an error...

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1060:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1108:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

But look! NodeJS considers it a keyword. The question is, is there a right way?

Comment: `enum` doesn't do anything currently. It's just a reserved keyword for the futuer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the MDN source you linked, `enum` has been reserved for future use, but the functionality has not been implemented yet. You can either use the [enum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enum) package, or use something like Typescript that does implement enums.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, its [section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords) is *Future Reserved Keywords*, which

> They have no special functionality at present, but they might at some future time, so they cannot be used as identifiers.

Currently, [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) is supported in JS's superset, Typescript